# User interface for relational database: basic feature

Tags: ms-access, user-interface, rdbms, foreign-key-relationship

This is a bit embarrassing but it's been a while.

When working with relational databases and linking to separate tables by primary:foreign keys, in 1-∞, such that, in a particular table, the table's foreign relationship returns an integer ID... how do you go about making this relationship intelligible to users?

For example:

You have a **company** table

- CID
- CompanyName
- CompanyLocation
- CompanyBusinessType

etc (not actual column names)

and an **employee** table

- EID
- firstName
- surName
- DOB
- email
- company

Employee *company* is related to CID. But some user putting in information about an employee would have to know the ID code for the particular company due to the nature of the relationship. You can run a query to return 'CompanyName's along with their associated 'CID's which can then be searched, but this cipher is hardly an ideal solution. I just cannot remember the theory of how one approaches this, even though I'm certain I've done it before. I need to implement it in both Microsoft Access 2010 and Microsoft SSMS (separate databases fwiw); but the execution should be relatively straightforward as soon as I remember how it's done!

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft Access form?

Comment: Sure. I'll be porting the db to Sharepoint but I don't believe that there should be any problem carrying over Access forms (unlike a similar migration to SQL Server)

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but I think Sharepoint is the one excuse for look-up fields in tables. In general, look-up fields in tables are poison http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402351(office.14).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a combo box with 2 columns.  One column as the company name and the other as the company ID.  You can set the width of the company ID to 0 if you don't want the user to see it.

This can be done with the Property Sheet on MS-Access Forms

Set the Row Source of the combo box to:
`SELECT CompanyName, CompanyID FROM Company;`

Set the Control Source of the combo box to:`Employee.CompanyID`

Also make sure the Row Source Type is set to `Table/Query`

Comment: Ok - that's great; just one issue. If the table from which Companies is being selected is already compete, then there is no issue. But, in all likelihood the user will encounter a new company someday. As it stands it is possible to overwrite an existing company in the company table, but how on earth can it be that another company be appended to the company table? Would the user specifically have to update the company table before attempting to add an employee to the undocumented company?

Comment: What is the relationship between company and employee?

Comment: The Control Source would technically be `Employee.CompanyID` not `Company.CompanyID`, so it will update only the companyID in the employee table.

Comment: Relationship between company and employee would naturally be one to many (one company can have many employees). I'm afraid I don't entirely know what you mean by Control Source. If I remember correctly Control Source is for on the fly Visual Basic? But I'm probably coming to the conclusion at this stage that in the event of meeting someone from an undocumented company that the employee could be listed under a company named "undefined", until the company details are added.

Comment: Just put a button next to the combo box which opens the "insert new company" form (which you already have, I guess) as a dialog and refreshes the combo box after that. --> If someone enters a new employee and the company is not yet in the combo box, he can immediately open the "insert new company" form, save the company there and then it's in the combo box and he can select it.

Comment: That's a great help thanks and is working well. Just wondering; can this combo-box method still work where there is no direct relationship between tables? E.g. Kane's example below of using an intermediate table in order to create a many-to-many relationship: will the combo box still work as a solution if, from the form design POV, you pretend the intermediate table doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a many to many relationship (many employees belong to many companies) then you will need another table `CompanyEmployees`, something like this: -

[image: Many to many relationship example]

If an employee only belongs to one company then this structure will do fine: -

[image: simple relationship]

In either case you will need to display the user with some form of drop down list when adding / editing a user to associate the users with one or more companies.

Comment: Yup; know (and remember) the intermediate table methodology, thanks! The question relates to the association of IDs with user-readable columns. Nice graphic btw!

Comment: It the "In either case you will need to display the user with some form of drop down list when adding / editing a user to associate the users with one or more companies." bit that I'm having trouble with!